# R adding word in the middle of grid arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing R ggplot, and I am arranging multiple plots with `grid.arrange`.

Is there a way to add some words in in between two plots?
I want the output to be like the red word.

Thank you for your help :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
P1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram()
P2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_histogram()
grid.arrange(P1, *I want to add some information here*,P2, ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `grid.text` function from `grid` library as follows

```
### Libraries
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

### Data
data(cars)

### Initiating plots
P1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram()

P2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_histogram()

### Display plots
grid.arrange(P1, P2, ncol = 1, nrow = 2)+
grid.text("I want to add some information here", 
          x=unit(0.25, "npc"), 
          y=unit(.52, "npc"),
          gp=gpar(fontsize=20, col="red"))
```

[image]

Comment: How to control the word to be in the middle? Thank you.

Comment: You can play with values in `x=unit(0.25, "npc")` (x axis) or `y=unit(.52, "npc")` (y axis). Here if you increase x then it will be shifted to the right

Comment: You also have the following options from `grid.text`: `just='center'` but it won't center exactly where you want ; `hjust=TRUE` and `vjust=TRUE` instead of `x=unit(0.25, "npc")` or `y=unit(.52, "npc")` respectively but it won't center where you want. What is centered in these options is the very top left pixel of the first word from your sentence, this said you can see the issue of centering the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create another `ggplot` with only text that you want and use it in `cowplot::plot_grid`

```
library(ggplot2)

P1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_histogram()

P2 <- ggplot() + 
  annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, size=8, 
           label = "This is some text in the middle", color = "red") + 
  theme_void() 

P3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) +  geom_histogram()

cowplot::plot_grid(P1, P2, P3, rel_heights = c(1/2, 1/12, 1/2), 
                   align = "v", nrow = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the word image to be left-aligned?